# loading icon & get values fom "shell_exec" result while php loading

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, response, shell-exec

[ loading icon & get values fom "shell_exec"  response while php loading][1]

Hi, I have a little knowledge in PHP, I need when a PHP page is loaded, automatically show information from a "shell_exec" results, actually, it's the IMEIs from connected USB modems, also the icon for the signal while being selected "from 4 icons" based on the level of the signal which also a result of "shell_exec"

I need to change src="foler/xx.png based on 4 conditions

```
<td class="neo-table-data-row table_data"><img title="" src="foler/xx.png"> dongle0</font></td>
```

Comment: Is there any php code that you've tried? `shell_exec` returns the output data unless there is a problem executing commands. Ex: `$output = shell_exec('YOUR COMMAND');`

Comment: I need to print/echo $output  at my attached image "None" under operator

Comment: I updated the post and posted my code